# SailsJS View Layer Separation with CSRF

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I am curious about whether or not, and how, it would be possible to completely separate a sailsJS app from the View Layer. That is to not manage templates, views, client-side JS, and assets in a way that's coupled with what is just meant as a RESTful API in my case. I want to try and deploy two separate repositories that do not need to know how the other works that interact with each other by requests.

I know about the `sails new <apiName> --no-frontend` option but I would also like to incorporate CSRF tokens on my forms that doesn't do it in the suggested `ejs` method with an `<input type='hidden' name='_csrf' value='<%= _csrf %>'>`.

Would it be possible and recommended for my case to expose an endpoint that deals strictly with granting and validating csrf tokens on my sailsJS server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just scrap everything that has to do with the front-end (`--no-frontend` is a good start). The `csrf` hook and `GET /csrfToken` are still there if you don't generate a front-end, but sails will require a `_csrf` parameter whenever you `POST`, `PUT`, et cetera, if the CSRF hook is enabled.

Within your sails app, whenever you handle a route, you do not have to return `res.view()` or `res.render()`; you can return `res.json()` or anything of that ilk.

For example, we use [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) to manage our assets separately from sails; such that sails only handles API requests, not static files or rendering.

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know there was a route for csrf tokens.